# Find the daylight savings status of a naive datetime given the timezone

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a canonical way to discover the daylight savings status of a local timestamp that is missing timezone info.

I have a naive timestamp:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 12, 5, 0)
```

I know that this timestamp was generated by a server at US/Pacific that is daylight savings aware -- so it could be at utc-0700 or utc-0800 depending on the time of year.

Is there an easy way to do this? Or do I need to use a hack like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone

tz = timezone('US/Pacific')

# get all the transition times for the pacific timezone
ttimes = list(map(lambda x: x-timedelta(hours=8), tz._utc_transition_times))
summers = {}
for n, t in enumerate(ttimes):
    try:
        # find the pairs of transition times that start in the spring
        if t.month < 7:
            summers[t.year] = (ttimes[n], ttimes[n+1])
    except:
        pass

def is_daylight_savings(dt):
    return summers[dt.year][0] <= dt < summers[dt.year][1]
```

So:

```
>>> is_daylight_savings(datetime(2016, 3, 13, 5, 0))
True
>>> is_daylight_savings(datetime(2016, 3, 13, 1, 0))
False
```

Comment: Based on the duplicate, it sounds like all you need is [localize](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) and [dst](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.dst).